# Cordova : Radio button selection is slow in iOS only (10.0)

Tags: ios

I have developed application using Cordova, for front end work I have used HTML, CSS and AngularJS. I am facing performance problem with iOS, in android same code working perfectly.
I am using radio button in LI tag, in LI tag I have used ng-repeat and dynamically making radio button list.

**Issue :** Now the issue is when I select any radio button in list then the selection of radio button is slow. It is occurring only in iOS, in android it is working fine.

Can any one help me here to improve performance for iOS only.

Is performance problem with Latest iOS version only ?

Is anyone aware with such type of problem ?

Please any one suggest me what can I do to resolve that problem.

Thanks

Mohit Jain